# Wordpress code snippet (with shortcode to call it) to switch between two user roles - email subscriber or not

Tags: wordpress, user-roles, bulk-email

I have a WP site with registered users. I send them only one bulk email every month so there is no need for a bigger mass mail solution - so far this is enough. The disadvantage of this solution is that there is no option for the user to unsubscribe using either a link in the email or a checkbox or button in the user page in WP - only by replying to the email with a written request that I can fulfill by changing the user role from Visitor to custom role Unsubscribed.

Sending is done by "Send Users Email (Premium)" plugin that has function to send emails to user groups.  Because all and all the users management isn't big I am able to handle these few requests manually.

However I was thinking of upgrading it in a way that users can have an option to handle the subsription by themselves.

I am thinking of adding a button to the account page that would toggle the current signed user role between Visitor and Unsubsribed (best with a different role names or labels like   I (don't) want to recieve monthly news).

So I am thinking of a code snippet with a shortcode that could be called by this button or maybe a checkbox?

Can you please supply a working solution for this?